# Запуск длительно работающей функции с отслеживанием состояния через флаг

Tags: python, asyncio

У меня есть следующий класс:

```
class model:

    IS_EMPTY = 0        
    RUNNING = 1
    SUCCESS = 2
    Train = IS_EMPTY

    def doing(self, SOME_TODO):
        #Если нет того, что надо делать
        if not SOME_TO_DO:
            self.Train = IS_EMPTY
            return

        self.Train = RUNNING
        SOME_TODO ... #Это некий объект, надо которым надо вести длительную работу
        ...

        #Когда работа завершилась
        self.Train = SUCCESS

    def is_doing(self):
        return self.Train
```

Подразумевается, что функция doing делает некие длительные операции. О том, как проходит работа функции doing, можно судить по состоянию переменной Train. Я хочу реализовать функцию doing таким образом, чтобы она работала как асинхронная (не силен в терминологии), а пользователь, при проверке состояния получал состояние Train. По понятным причинам, следующий код заставит пользователя ждать, пока doing закончит работу:

```
mod = model()

def work:
    if (mod.is_doing == mod.RUNNING):
        return mod.RUNNING

    if (mod.is_doing == mod.SUCCESS):
        return mod.SUCCESS

    if (mod.is_doing == mod.IS_EMPTY):
        #И вот тут вызывается функция doing, которая стопорит все
        #до своего завершения
        mod.doing(OBJECT_TODO)
```

Может ли asyncio помочь в решении подобных задач? Или есть более практичные методы?

Comment: Длительные операции бывают очень разные. Если это вычислительные задачи - дело одно, если это IO (например, много операций с БД) - дело другое.

Comment: Потому и спрашиваю, что не хватает знаний. Операции вычислительные.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если функция, которую вы не хотите ждать занимается вычислительной работой, то `asyncio` тут не помощник. Асинхронность может достигаться несколькими путями - использованием нескольких потоков, процессов, [сопрограмм](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553704/what-is-a-coroutine) и пр. Сопрограмма может сохранить свое состояние и переключиться на выполнение другой сопрограммы (или "основной" код). Простой пример (Py3.5+):

```
import asyncio
GLOBAL_COUNTER = 10
GLOBAL_LOOP = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def coroutine_1():
    global GLOBAL_COUNTER, GLOBAL_LOOP
    print("CORO 1")
    await asyncio.sleep(3, GLOBAL_LOOP)
    GLOBAL_COUNTER -= 1

async def coroutine_2():
    global GLOBAL_COUNTER, GLOBAL_LOOP
    print("CORO 2")
    await asyncio.sleep(6, GLOBAL_LOOP)
    GLOBAL_COUNTER -= 1


while GLOBAL_COUNTER > 0:
    GLOBAL_LOOP.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(coroutine_1(), coroutine_2()))
    print("GLOBAL!")
```

Сопрограмма_2 не ожидает, когда закончит спать первая. При выполнении `await sleep` в первой сопрограмме, вторая могла что-то сделать, не дожидаясь первую. И так далее, третья не дожидается вторую и первую, четвертая и т.д. Однако, нюанс в том, что `asyncio.sleep` - это имитация ожидания, не работы. Ожидания ответа от БД, от другого сервера, от устройства, от диска. То есть во время ожидания ЦП простаивает/ждет ответа/ждет прерывания и async/await не дают ему этого делать, подкидывая задач. Теперь заменим первую сопрограмму:

```
import time

async def coroutine_1():
    print("CORO 1")
    time.sleep(3)
```

`time.sleep()` - имитация вычислительной задачи, которая забивает ЦП полностью. То есть никто никого не ждет, ЦП занят, он не может взять и переключиться куда-то еще - задач и так хватает с лихвой. Обратите внимание, что все это богатство происходит в одном потоке (на одном ядре ЦП), сопрограммы не порождают новых потоков или процессов. Я придумал еще аналогию - представьте, что вы ждете автобус. Вместо того, чтобы пялиться в небо - можно почитать книжку. Однако, читать вряд ли возможно во время того, как вы пишете код (хотя всякие есть индивидуумы).

Для того, чтобы основная программа не ждала какую-то долгую функцию можно использовать процессы (не потоки). Скрипты, исполняемые Python в реализации CPython - всегда, за некоторыми исключениями, однопоточны. См. [GIL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock). Однопоточны - значит в них работает только одно ядро ЦП, даже несмотря на то, что с точки зрения ОС потоков несколько.

Однако, некоторые библиотеки (или самописные расширения) могут отпускать GIL, тем самым используя все доступные ядра ЦП. Самая известная - это `numpy`. Попробуйте использовать именно `numpy` для того, чтобы молотить числа - прирост скорости огромен, особенно если ваши вычисления можно векторизовать.

Возвращаясь к процессам - можно попробовать организовать параллельные вычисления, используя модуль `multiprocessing` - процессы полностью независимы друг от друга.

Если у вас целый океан задач и одна машина не справляется - пришло время для `Celery` - с помощью этой библиотеки можно раскидать задачи на кластере из нескольких компьютеров.

Также возможны иные выходы из положения, все не заканчивается на этих библиотеках и можно найти библиотеки для решения каких-то узких задач (например, CUDA/OpenCL для вычисления на GPU, Tensorflow для машинного обучения)

Comment: 1- никогда не блокируйте `async` функцию без вызова `await` (иначе вы весь цикл событий останавливаете). К примеру, вместо `time.sleep(3)`, следует использовать `await asyncio.sleep(3)`. Чтобы показать пример долгих вычислений, можно `await loop.run_in_executor(executor, long_computations, *args)` подставить (`executor` может выполнять код в пуле потоков/процессов -- что необходимо). 2- Вместо `asyncio`, можно показать пример с `futures.concurrent` как запустить функцию, не блокируя текущий поток (`.submit()`), и проверить статус выполнения позже или  вызвать callback с результатами.