# Асинхронность в пайтон

Tags: python, асинхронность

Пытаюсь разобраться в асинхронности в `python`, но никак не найду ни материалов толковых, ни в документации материал нормального не изложен (точнее ничего найти не могу даже, кроме модуля `asyncio`, что вводит в заблуждение, ибо в PEP 492 якобы есть варианты реализации без него, насколько я понял).

Может кто-нибудь объяснить что к чему? Или ссылок каких подкинет с норм инфой?

В общем, на данный момент есть следующие вопросы:

Как это работает и с чем это едят?

Как правильно применять асинхронность?

Можно ли применять асинхронность вне серверной разработки?

Обязателен ли модуль `asyncio`?

Спасибо!

Comment: Переформулируйте пожалуйста вопрос, а именно конкретнее о асинхронности, меня тоже интересует эта тема, хотелось бы получить более общий ответ. И будет полезно для остальных интересующихся.

Comment: @Alban обновил вопрос. Желаете что-нибудь добавить?

Comment: [Немного инфы по теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/639850/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3/639952#639952)

Comment: @m9_psy я читал до этого ещё, плюсанул, очень хороший ответ. Но хотелось бы более подробного рассмотрения, чтобы полностью во все аспекты вникнуть. Хотя бы на базовом уровне

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Работает поверх системных вызовов select/epool. Едят это вместе с I/O операциями.
2. Тут наверное вопрос костылей и практики. Единственное что могу сказать, что не надо в асинхронный код пихать CPU задачи (числодробилки),  потому что такая задача не делает I/O,  и весь event-loop встанет.
   Еще одна проблема - есть уже достаточно много синхронных I/O библиотек (requests, драйвера к БД, и.т.д) которые просто так не сделаешь асинхронными, и использование которых в асинхронном коде подвесит event loop. Поэтому прежде чем начинать новый проект, или переписывать старый нужно быть уверенным, что в наличии есть необходимые инструменты.
3. Асинхронность можно применять где угодно, где есть I/O операции, просто на бэкендах их особенно много (прими запрос, сходи в базу, отдай ответ, дерни другой бэкенд). Я могу себе представить такую задачу не для бэкенда. Например у вас есть 1000 датчиков (IoT, все дела), которые надо переодически опрашивать. Это может быть обычный скрипт на домашнем компьютере.
4. PEP 492 - это стандарт, синтаксис. Каким образом будет реализован event loop стандарт вроде не описывает. Еще до этого стандарта были реализации асинхронных библиотек (прим. Tornado). В стандартную библиотеку включили event loop - asyncio ( в прошлом [tulip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulip_(python_project)) ). Поверх asyncio уже начали строить экосистему ([aiohttp](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/), [asyncpg](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg), итд) для разработки приложений. Есть и другие реализации event loop ([dabeaz/curio](https://github.com/dabeaz/curio), [python-trio/trio](https://github.com/python-trio/trio)), следовательно модуль asyncio не обязателен.